# How can you have the Input Manager Axis values snap to 1 (or -1)?

Tags: unity, input

When a selected key is pressed in Unity, the Input Manager's `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` function returns a gradually increasing number up to `1` (or negatively `-1`) for the length it is held down. The rate at which it increases is based on the value `Sensitivity` in the Input Manager. Similarly, the sticks on a controller return a value depending on how far they are tilted.

Is there a proper way to make the value immediately snap to -1 or 1 through the manager, or would I have to write a couple of `if` statements in my script to handle that?\

Edit: A very short and readable scripting option would be `if (Mathf.Abs(isRunning) > 0) isRunning = Mathf.Sign(isRunning);`

Comment: Something wrong with `if(value < 0) {...} else if (value > 0){...}`?

Comment: You could just cast the return value to an int. Thus you'll get -1 or 1 once the appropriate button is pressed. For more precision you could take a look at Math.Round.

Comment: This is more for curiosity, it seems crazy that this option isn't available in the manager

Comment: If you're using a keyboard, What's wrong with Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");?   http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for @Savlon. I think that should be the accepted answer if you would convert it to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
```

Reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html

If you are wanting the value to be -1, 0 or 1, use GetAxisRaw for keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to do it the if statement way.

For instance...

For the value to be either 1 or -1:

```
int amount = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 ? 1 : -1;
```

For the value to be 1, 0, or -1:

```
float f;
int amount = (f=Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) > 0 ? 1 : f < 0 ? -1 : 0;
```

Comment: The first statement is a bad idea since it's never zero. Zero indicates no key is pressed. The second statement is overly complicated as a one-liner, and would be easier to break out into multiple statements (in my opinion).

Comment: Good points, I don't disagree.

Comment: That's too bad, I'm really disappointed there isn't such a trivial setting available